# Setting value to mutable live data twice only triggers the onChangedCallback once

Tags: android, mvvm, android-livedata

I am calling methods in viewModel to set data on my mutable live data like below and they are being called one after the other exactly like below:

```
    viewModel.onCountrySelected(country);
    viewModel.onLanguageSelected(language);
```

Then in the view model I set the data on the mutable live data is I am observing in my fragment. The methods in my view model are below:

```
public void onLanguageSelected(int type) {
    clickType.setValue(type);

}

public void onCountrySelected(int type) {
    clickType.setValue(type);
}
```

clickType is my Mutable Live data. Now the problem is that my onChanged is only called once and that too only for the last value that I set on clickType.

If I am not wrong I onChanged should be triggered twice since I am setting the value on the clickType twice.

```
private void initLiveData()
{
    clickType = new MutableLiveData<>();
    clickType.setValue(0);
}
```

initLiveData is where I am initialising the MutableLiveData. Also I am calling the initLiveData after setting the veiwModel variable to the layout.

In the fragment:

```
binding.setViewModel(viewModel);
viewModel.initLiveData()


   viewModel.getClickType().observe(this, new Observer<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable Integer type) {

            handleClicks(type);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you share the declaration part of clickType and observe pattern

Comment: Share observe pattern. how you are retrieving clickType ?

Comment: edited please check

Comment: I think clickType reference is changing while observe.

Instead of initializing clickType inside init() method, do it in declaration part.
int clickType = new MutableLivadata<>();

Comment: no that didn't help.

Comment: MutableLivadata<Integer> clickType = new MutableLivadata<>();

Comment: Yes that's what I did in my view model class

Comment: Double check that you are not using `postValue`

Comment: no I am using setValue.